# Why does the Responsive File Manager add random number to the img url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I am using [this file manager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) with tinymce to allow me to upload images to my website. The problem is that when I upload an image then use tinymce to add the image to my post the image appears with a random number at the end of the url.

Example:

If the image uploaded has the url

> mysite.com/imgs/image.png

Then when I add the image to my post the image appears like this

`<img src="mysite.com/imgs/image.png?1472141410397">`

Where does the question mark and random number come from and does anyone know how to disable it?

Comment: It's a cache buster.

Comment: @Barmar, Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: This is used to ensure you'll read the actual image from the server instead of a cached version. It can be used manually, for example you have an image and you want to update it but your users will see the cached version, so you can do `...img.jpg?v2`

Comment: Is there a reason why you want it removed? Does it cause any issues for you?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes, doesn't this slow the site because the browser has to read the images every time?

Comment: Yes, it does. This is used when you'll be modifying something on the image and want your users to see the latest version instead of the cached one. But if you'll be using always the same image you don't need it.

Comment: Definitely not a "random" number. It's a javascript millisecond timestamp, and corresponds to Aug 25/2016, 10:10am (in my TZ). So, yeah... cache buster. You probably DON'T want to remove it.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes, So isn't it better to disable this feature and If I ever modify an image then I'll add the random number myself.

Comment: In your case, yes it would be. But I'm not familiar with this plugin so I don't know how to disable cache.